# Is there a way to update enum variables with new states in C++?

Tags: c++, types, enums, set

I want to know if there is a way to update an enum variable in C++ giving the program new states dynamically. For example, I create a void enum variable for the days of the week, and then, I want to let the user enter the days to update the enum variable.

Comment: No, an enum  has to be defined at compile time.

Comment: The point of an enum is to have a distinct type with the identifiers for different values able to be used in the *source code*.  So, it doesn't make sense to think of adding new identifiers - like say `Tuesday` - to an enum at runtime (when the user can enter things) - as the code has already been compiled (and you couldn't have used `Tuesday` therein because it didn't exist in the enum definition).

Comment: Extending an enum is a concept which always starts with good intentions and then creates chaos for anyone who has to deal with it later. I find it humorous that even python took a pass on extending enums. So, don't do it. Think about the problem you're trying to solve some more. Hopefully a better solution will reveal itself.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem that if discussed may have a clean and better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, I create a void enum variable for the days of the week, and then, I want to let the user enter the days to update the enum variable.

No, that's not how enums work in c++. They are only a fixed set of numerically representable values, where that set is completely defined at compile time.

Enumerated values:

- must be defined completely (all of them) at compile time
- cannot be extended with newly introduced values at runtime
- do not have a standard representation as human readable text

What you need is a mapping between user input (let's suppose string data), and the predefined enum values, e.g. something like

```
enum class Weekday { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday };

std::string Weekday2String(Weekday wd) {
    switch(wd) {
         case Weekday::Monday: return "Mon";
         case Weekday::Tuesday: return "Tue";
         case Weekday::Wednesday: return "Wed";
         case Weekday::Thursday: return "Thu";
         case Weekday::Friday: return "Fri";
         case Weekday::Saturday: return "Sat";
         case Weekday::Sunday: return "Sun";
    }
    throw std::exception("Unexpected enum value.")
}

Weekday string2Weekday(const std::string& input) {
    if(input == "Mon") { return Weekday::Monday; }
    if(input == "Tue") { return Weekday::Tuesday; }
    if(input == "Wed") { return Weekday::Wednesday; }
    if(input == "Thu") { return Weekday::Thursday; }
    if(input == "Fri") { return Weekday::Friday; }
    if(input == "Sat") { return Weekday::Saturday; }
    if(input == "Sun") { return Weekday::Sunday; }
    throw std::exception("Invalid weekday string.")
}
```

You can use these functions then in routines, which require weekday input from a user interface.

---

Note:

- There are more sophisticated methods to define the above mentioned functions (e.g. as cast operator definitions for a simple class managing a `Weekday` value, or stream oriented overloads for the `std::ostream::operator<<()` and `std::istream::operator>>()`), but it boils down to the above in the end.
- If you want to have it configurable, what the user wants to input for a specific weekday (e.g. `"povjaj"`<sup>1</sup> for `Weekday::Tuesday`), you have to encapsulate the enum into a class, which provides to set the `std::string` values for each `Weekday` value, and keeps these in extra variables.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Unfortunately there's still no proper klingon to Unicode mapping nowadays.</sub>